# How to extract RDF triples with specific predicates using sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, triplestore

I uploaded a set of RDF triples onto a local Virtuoso endpoint.

Of all these triples, I would like to extract only those whose subjects have at least the predicates http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label and http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment.

For example, from these triples:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AccessibleComputing> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "AccessibleComputing"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AfghanistanGeography> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "AfghanistanGeography"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AfghanistanGeography> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment> " ... " .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Austroasiatic_languages> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment> " ... " .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AccessibleComputing> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Computer_accessibility> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AfghanistanGeography> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Afghanistan_Geography> .
```

I would like to get:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AfghanistanGeography> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "AfghanistanGeography"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AfghanistanGeography> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment> " ... " .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AfghanistanGeography> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Afghanistan_Geography> .
```

Is it possible to do this with one (or more) SPARQL query?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a `CONSTRUCT WHERE` query:

```
CONSTRUCT WHERE {
    ?s rdfs:label ?label.
    ?s rdfs:comment ?comment.
    ?s ?p ?o
}
```

This is a simplified form of `CONSTRUCT` that can be used when the `CONSTRUCT {}` part and the `WHERE {}` part are identical.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `DESCRIBE`, e.g.:

```
DESCRIBE ?s 
WHERE {
  ?s rdfs:label ?label .
  ?s rdfs:comment ?comment .
}
```

or alternatively with `CONSTRUCT` :

```
CONSTRUCT { ?subject ?predicate ?object} 
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object .
  FILTER EXISTS {
     ?subject rdfs:label ?label .
     ?subject rdfs:comment ?comment .
  }
}
```

Comment: The behaviour of `DESCRIBE` depends on the SPARQL store, and it may include extra triples that are not desirable, or omit triples that are wanted. So depending on the store being used, it may not be a good choice.